Mittag-Leffler condition for large indexing sets
Consider a cofiltered diagram $I\ni i\mapsto X_{i}$ of sets. If $I$ is countable and the transition maps $X_{i}\to X_{j}$ are (eventually) surjective, then the inverse limit $\varprojlim_{i\in I}X_{i}$ is non-empty.
Is this statement still correct when $I$ is not countable?

Here is a counterexample.
Let $I=\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal. For each $\alpha\in \omega_1$ (i.e., $\alpha$ is a countable ordinal), let $X_\alpha$ be the set of all injective functions $f\colon \alpha\to \omega$ such that $\omega\setminus \mathrm{ran}(f)$ is infinite. When $\alpha<\beta$, define the transition map $X_\beta\to X_\alpha$ by restriction $f\mapsto f|_\alpha$. This is a cofiltered diagram of sets.
I claim that each transition map is surjective. Fix $\alpha<\beta$ and $f\in X_\alpha$. Since $\omega\setminus \mathrm{ran}(f)$ is infinite, it can be partitioned into two infinite sets, $Y$ and $Z$. Now since $\beta\setminus \alpha$ is at most countable, we can pick an injective function $g\colon (\beta\setminus \alpha)\to Y$. Then $f'=f\cup g$ is an injective function $\beta\to \omega$, and $Z\subseteq \omega\setminus\mathrm{ran}(f')$ is infinite, so $f'\in X_\beta$ restricts to $f$.
However, $\varprojlim_{\alpha\in \omega_1}X_\alpha$ is empty, since a point of the limit would determine a coherent family of injective functions $\alpha\to\omega$ for all $\alpha\in\omega_1$, whose union would be an injective function $\omega_1\to \omega$, which is absurd.
